# NetworkManager(dhclient) fails to update DNS server

Tags: wifi, dns, networkmanager, dhcp

I'm getting troubles trying to navigate in a new network,
Network manager starts `dhclient` as follows:

```
root       981  0.0  0.0  16124  3660 ?        S    11:31   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-wlp2s0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-86860822-137b-4f50-8264-35592aa57ad7-wlp2s0.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlp2s0.conf wlp2s0
```

Anyway It doesn't updates `resolv.conf` with the received DNS server.

If I open the `.lease` file there are offered leases with appropriate name servers, I also get back an ip address that I can regularly see through `ifconfig`. 
If I open Wireshark I can also see the offered lease and the DHCP that sends back DNS option correctly.

Anyway the only way to make my network work is to manually add the DNS server provided by the DHCP (readed from Wireshark or in the lease file :/) to the `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

If I add the wifi interface into `/etc/network/interfaces` such as:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Network manager will not work but DNS will, `resolv.conf` will be correctly updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved this issue searching into the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and under the `[main]` section there was a `dns` filed that apparently was causing troubles. I removed it.

The man page says that if we remove the `dns` field from network manager .conf file it will update regularly `/etc/resolv.conf` as I want.